# Is Chamilo 1.8's 'Enable Time Control' buggy for the Asia region?

Tags: php, timezone

I am evaluating Chamilo 1.8.* and I have found that the Enable Time Control does not work properly. What happens is:

- For a time controlled test of 2 minutes, the timer beings with a countdown timer of 32 minutes
- After 2 minutes duration of the test, however, the test ends, at 30:00 minutes.

I have noticed that this problem is specific to people logging in from Asia region, since I faced this problem even at Chamilo's own test server at http://chamilodev.beeznest.com/ where the dev team did not face any trouble, and could not replicate it.

Precisely, my problem is the same as this:
http://support.chamilo.org/issues/4707

But the dev team from the Americas do not seem to be able to replicate the problem.
Did anyone from India/Pakistan/Bangaldesh/Asia region face this problem?

I have ensured that

1. My server time is set to my local time zone.
2. My Chamilo installation server time (the option in Chamilo) is set to my local time zone.

Does anyone here have a clue about it?

Comment: After wrecking my head a lot, and talking to a no. of people from Asia/Kolkata region, I have found that for some users the timer begins with 30 mins added to the original time, like people in North India, and for most people in Southern India see the timer right.

Comment: I could not figure out why though. Its just the same problem wher devs from the Americas and Europe see the countdown time working fine, while users from India see the same problem replicated, even at their own test server at http://chamilodev.beeznest.com/

Answer (score 0):

A faster way to solve your problem would be to upgrade to a later version of Chamilo (1.9.2 for example) or to upgrade the version of the epiclock library, as suggested in the report. If upgrading to 1.9.2 doesn't help, it will at least enable the developers to help you out on an officially-supported version (which will increase your chances of having it fixed).

The Chamilo dev team itself is mainly made of people in Europe, by the way (I'm the only one in "Americas").

Did you try changing your timezone to some other that is only 1/2h different from yours? I guess you must have a 30 minutes difference with some areas near you, am I right?

Comment: I am on 1.9.2 now. The problem persists. As I said before, I could see the problem even on the test setver at http://chamilodev.beeznest.com/ while the dev team could not. Currently both my php settings via WMH and Chamilo settings are at Asia/Kolkata, but still a time control of two minutes appears as 32 minutes and so on. Is it something to do with cache? Or some test left midway?

Answer (score 0):

Check your timezone PHP settings:

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Shanghai"
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.configuration.php

By the way, you should use http://stable.chamilo.org (latest code for the next stable version Chamilo 1.9.4) instead of chamilodev.

Comment: I am using a stable version. The problem is that the bug is very much inherent across all versions, but somehow users/dev from Europe are not able to replicate it, as pointed out here http://support.chamilo.org/issues/4707